# Visual Basic set User Agent with ReadXml

Tags: vb.net, user-agent, readxml

I'm trying to set the user agent for a request with XmlRead. I googled a lot about this and couldn't find the answer. Here is my chunk of code:

```
 Dim RssData As DataSet
        Dim Title As String
        Dim Url As String
        Dim Stream As String
        Dim buffer As Integer
        RssData = New DataSet()
        RssData.ReadXml("http://localhost/user_agent.php")
        buffer = 0
        For Each RssRow As DataRow In RssData.Tables("entry").Rows
            Title = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(RssRow.Item("title").ToString, 30)
            Stream += Title & vbCrLf

        Next
        LinkLabel3.Text = Stream

        For Each RssRow As DataRow In RssData.Tables("entry").Rows
            Title = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(RssRow.Item("title").ToString, 30)
            Url = RssRow.Item("url").ToString
            LinkLabel3.Links.Add(buffer, Title.Length, Url)
            buffer = buffer + Title.Length + 2
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the code that actually performs the web request is buried pretty deep so you'd have to inherit a bunch of code to do what you asked for. Instead, let me suggest a different path, download the XML on your own with code that's easy to set that header, and then load that into the dataset. The `WebClient` class lets you set arbitrary headers and has a simple `DownloadString` method. Once you've got that you can wrap it in a `MemoryStream` and pass that into `ReadXml()`. (I couldn't find a way to read the XML as a string, that's why I was forced to read it as `Stream`.)

```
    ''//Will hold our downloaded XML
    Dim MyXml As String

    ''//Create a webclient to download our XML
    Using WC As New System.Net.WebClient()
        ''//Manually set the user agent header
        WC.Headers.Add("user-agent", "your user agent here")
        ''//Download the XML
        MyXml = WC.DownloadString("http://localhost/user_agent.php")
    End Using
    ''//Create our dataset object
    Dim RssData As New DataSet()
    ''//There is no direct method to load XML as a string (at least that I could find) so we will
    ''//    convert it to a byte array and load it into a memory stream
    Dim Bytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MyXml)
    Using MS As New System.IO.MemoryStream(Bytes)
        ''//Load the stream into the reader
        RssData.ReadXml(MS)
    End Using

    ''//Your code continues normally here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. I heard ReadXml is not the best way to do the job, but using other ways I couldn't set them into a DataSet() . Thanks again.